# FineUploader - return success: false on DELETE request

Tags: delete-file, fine-uploader

I'm handling deleting files with custom Wordpress script:

```
if ( ! wp_verify_nonce($_POST['nonce'],'delete_attachment_'.$_POST['attachment_id']) ) {
        $response['success'] = 'false';
        echo json_encode($response);
        exit();

    } else {

        $attach_id = $_POST['attachment_id'];

        if ($attach_id) {
            wp_delete_attachment( $attach_id, true );
            $response['success'] = 'true';
        }
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
```

I tried to pass success: false, when the deleting fails, but the response in concole log seems to be always:

```
[FineUploader 4.2.2] Delete request for 'Clipboard02444.jpg' has succeeded.
```

How can I pass `success: false` to the DELETE method?

Comment: Please see the server-side documentation on the delete file request at http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/endpoint_handlers/traditional.html#deleting-files.

Comment: I would suggest you delete this question.